# <.ident> function/capture in perl6 grammars

Tags: regex, grammar, raku

While reading the Xml grammar for perl6 (https://github.com/supernovus/exemel/blob/master/lib/XML/Grammar.pm6), I am having some difficulties understanding the following token.

```
token pident {
  <!before \d> [ \d+ <.ident>* || <.ident>+ ]+ % '-'
}
```

More specifically <.ident>, there are no other definitions of ident, so I am assuming it is a reserved term. Though i cant find find a proper definition on perl6.org. Does anyone know what this means?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**TL;DR** I'll start with a precise and relatively concise answer. The rest of this answer is for those wanting to know more about built in rules in general and/or to drill down into `ident` in particular.

> `<.ident>` function/capture

Because of the `.`, `<.ident>` only matches, it doesn't capture<sup>[1]</sup>. For the rest of this answer I'll generally omit the `.` because it makes no difference to a rule's meaning besides the capture aspect.

Just as you can invoke (aka "call") one function within the declaration of another in programming languages, so too you can invoke a rule/token/regex/method (hereafter I'll generally just use the term "rule") within the declaration of another rule. `<foo>` is the syntax used to invoke a rule named `foo`; so `<ident>` invokes a  (method) named`ident`.

At the time I write this, `XML::Grammar` grammar does not itself define/declare a rule named `ident`. That means the call ends up dispatched to a *built in* declaration with that name.

The built in `ident` rule does precisely the same as if it were declared as:

```
token ident {
    [ <alpha> ]
    [ <alnum> ]*
}
```

The [official **Predefined character classes** doc](https://docs.raku.org/language/regexes#Predefined_character_classes) should provide precise definitions of `<alpha>` and `<alnum>`. Alternatively, the relevant details are also included later on in this answer.

The bottom line is that `ident` matches a string of one or more "alphanumeric" characters except that the first character cannot be a "number".

Thus both `abc` or `def123` match whereas `123abc` does not.

## The rest of this answer

For those interested in detail worth knowing I've written the following sections:

- ***Raku* (standard language and class details)**
- ***Rakudo* (high level implementation)**
- ***NQP* (mid level implementation)**
- ***MoarVM* (low level implementation)**
- **The specification and "specification" of `ident`**
- **(Corrections of) documentation of `<ident>`, "character class" and "identifier"**
- **`ident` vs Raku *identifiers***

## *Raku* (standard language and class details)

`XML::Grammar` is a user defined Raku grammar. A Raku grammar is a class. (["Grammars are really just slightly specialized classes"](https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/blob/b07e7b1d0ffcafc1f9dfbb3d56eff59c8eaddbf8/docs/metaobject-api.pod#grammarhow).)

A [Raku rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raku_rules) is a regex is a method:

```
grammar foo { rule ident { ... } }

say foo.^lookup('ident').WHAT; # (Regex)
say Regex ~~ Method;           # True
```

A rule *call*, like `<ident>`, in a grammar, is typically invoked as a result of calling [`.parse`](https://docs.raku.org/routine/parse) or similar on the grammar. The `.parse` call matches the input string according to the rules in the grammar.

When an occurrence of `<ident>` within `XML::Grammar` is evaluated during a match, the result is an `ident` method (rule) call on an instance of `XML::Grammar` (the `.parse` call creates an instance of its invocant if it's just a type object).

Because `XML::Grammar` does not itself define a rule/method of that name, the `ident` call is instead dispatched according to standard method resolution, er, rules. (I'm using the word "rules" here in the generic non-Raku specific sense. Ah, language.)

In Raku, any class created using a declaration of the form `grammar foo { ... }` automatically inherits from the `Grammar` class which in turn inherits from the `Match` class:

```
say .^mro given grammar foo {} # ((foo) (Grammar) (Match) (Capture) (Cool) (Any) (Mu))
```

`ident` is found in the built in `Match` class.

## Rakudo (high level implementation)

In the Rakudo compiler, [the `Match` class](https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/blob/master/src/core/Match.pm6) `does` the [role](https://docs.raku.org/language/typesystem#role) `NQPMatchRole`.

This `NQPMatchRole` is where the highest level implementation of `ident` is found.

## NQP (mid level implementation)

`NQPMatchRole` is written in the nqp language, a subset of Raku used to bootstrap the full Raku, and the heart of [NQP](https://github.com/perl6/nqp), a compiler toolkit.

Excerpting and reformatting just the most salient code from [the `ident` declaration](https://github.com/Raku/nqp/blob/3bbce8c3ab1f751fb9423a0fe2cb92a38d17f95b/src/QRegex/Cursor.nqp#L949-L965), the match for the *first* character boils down to:

```
   nqp::ord($target, $!pos) == 95
|| nqp::iscclass(nqp::const::CCLASS_ALPHABETIC, $target, $!pos)
```

This matches if the *first* character is *either* a `_` (`95` is the ASCII code / Unicode codepoint for an underscore) *or* a character matching a character class defined in NQP called `CCLASS_ALPHABETIC`.

The other bit of salient code is:

```
nqp::findnotcclass( nqp::const::CCLASS_WORD
```

This matches zero or more *subsequent* characters in the character class `CCLASS_WORD`.

A [search of NQP for `CCLASS_ALPHABETIC`](https://github.com/perl6/nqp/search?q=cclass_alphabetic) shows several matches. The most useful seems to be [an NQP test file](https://github.com/perl6/nqp/blob/master/t/nqp/095-cclass.t). While this file makes it clear that `CCLASS_WORD` is a superset of `CCLASS_ALPHABETIC`, it doesn't make it clear what those classes actually match.

NQP targets multiple "backends" or concrete virtual machines. Given the relative paucity of Rakudo/NQP doc/tests of what these rules and character classes actually match, one has to look at one of its backends to verify what's what.

## *MoarVM* (low level implementation)

[MoarVM](https://moarvm.org/) is the only officially supported backend.

A [search of MoarVM for `CCLASS`](https://github.com/MoarVM/MoarVM/search?q=cclass) shows several matches.

The important one seems to be [ops.c](https://github.com/MoarVM/MoarVM/blob/master/src/strings/ops.c) which [includes a `switch (cclass)` statement](https://github.com/MoarVM/MoarVM/blob/master/src/strings/ops.c#L2529) which in turn includes cases for `MVM_CCLASS_ALPHABETIC` and `MVM_CCLASS_WORD` that correspond to NQP's similarly named constants.

According to the code's comments:

`CCLASS_ALPHABETIC` currently matches exactly the same characters as the full Raku or NQP [`<:L>`](https://docs.raku.org/language/regexes#Unicode_properties) rule, i.e. the characters Unicode has classified as "Letters".

I think that means `<alpha>` is equivalent to the union of `CCLASS_ALPHABETIC` and `_` (underscore).

`CCLASS_WORD` matches the same plus `<:Nd>`, i.e. decimal digits (in any human language, not just English).

I think that means the Raku / NQP `<alnum>` rule is equivalent to `CCLASS_WORD`.

## The specification and "specification" of `ident`

The *official* specification of Raku is embodied in *roast*<sup>[2]</sup>.

A [search of roast for `ident`](https://github.com/perl6/roast/search?q=ident) shows several matches.

Most use `<ident>` only incidentally, as part of testing something else. The specification requires that they work as shown, but you won't understand what `<ident>` is supposed to do by looking at incidental usage.

Three tests clearly test `<ident>` itself. One of those is essentially redundant, leaving two. I see no changes between the `6.c` and `6.c.errata` versions of these two matches:

From [S05-mass/rx.t](https://github.com/perl6/roast/blob/856b60a41b452749d63238f76834f9de13e8e193/S05-mass/rx.t#L2073):

```
ok ('2+3 ab2' ~~ /<ident>/) && matchcheck($/, q/mob<ident>: <ab2 @ 4>/), 'capturing builtin <ident>';
```

`ok` tests that its first argument returns `True`. This call tests that `<ident>` skips `2+3`  and matches `ab2`.

From [S05-mass/charsets.t](https://github.com/perl6/roast/blob/6.c-errata/S05-mass/charsets.t#L13):

```
is $latin-chars.comb(/<ident>/).join(" "), "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ _ abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz ª µ º ÀÁÂÃÄÅÆÇÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÐÑÒÓÔÕÖ ØÙÚÛÜÝÞßàáâãäåæçèéêëìíîïðñòóôõö øùúûüýþÿ", 'ident chars';
```

`is` tests that its first argument matches its second. This call tests what the `ident` rule matches from a string consisting of the first 256 Unicode codepoints (the Latin-1 character set).

Here's a variation of this test that more clearly shows the matching that happens:

```
say ~$_ for $latin-chars ~~ m:g/<ident>/;
```

prints:

```
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
_
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
ª
µ
º
ÀÁÂÃÄÅÆÇÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÐÑÒÓÔÕÖ
ØÙÚÛÜÝÞßàáâãäåæçèéêëìíîïðñòóôõö
øùúûüýþÿ
```

But `<ident>` will match a whole lot more than just a hundred or so characters from Latin-1. So, while the above tests cover what `<ident>` is *officially specified/tested* to match, they clearly don't cover the full picture.

So let's look at the [official *speculation*](https://design.raku.org) that may, with care, be considered related to "specification".

First, we note the warning at the top:

```
Note: these documents may be out of date.
For Perl 6 documentation see docs.perl6.org;
for specs, see the official test suite.
```

The term "specs" in this warning is short for "specification". As already explained, the *official* specification test suite is *roast*, not any human language verbiage.

(Some people still think of these historical design docs as "specifications" too, and refer to them as "specs", but the official view is that "specs", as applied to the design docs, should be considered to be short for "speculations" to emphasize that they are not something to be fully relied upon.)

A [search for `ident` in design.raku.org](https://www.google.com/search?ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&domains=design.raku.org&sitesearch=design.raku.org&q=ident&btnG=Google+Search+the+Synopses) shows several matches.

The most useful match is in [the *Predefined Subrules* section of S05](https://design.raku.org/S05.html#Predefined_Subrules):

> These are some of the predefined subrules for any grammar or regex:

- ident ... Match an identifier.

Uhoh...

## (Corrections of) documentation of `<ident>`, "character class" and "identifier"

From [**Predefined character classes** in the official doc](https://docs.raku.org/language/regexes#Predefined_character_classes):

```
    Class                             Description
    <ident>                           Identifier. Also a default rule.
```

This is misleading in three ways:

- `ident` is **not** [a character class](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#Character_classes). Character classes match a *single* character in that character class; if used with a quantifier they just match a string of such characters, each of which can be any character from that class. In contrast `<ident>` matches a particular pattern of characters. It may be one character but you can't control that; the rule is greedy, matching as many characters fit the pattern. If you apply a quantifier it controls repetition of the overall rule, not how many characters are included in a single match of the rule.
- **All** built in rules are default rules. I think the default comment is there to emphasize that you can write your own `ident` rule if you don't like the built-in pattern. This is true for all rules though it will typically make much less sense to override built ins such as canonical character classes like `<lower>` (lowercase).
- `ident` does **not** match *identifiers*! Or, more accurately, it doesn't do so on its own for most Raku identifiers. See the next section for the details.

## `ident` vs Raku *identifiers*

```
my @Identifiers = < $bar %hash Foo Foo::Bar your_ident anothers' my-ident >; 
say (~$/ if m/^<ident>$/ for @Identifiers); # (Foo your_ident)
say (~$/ if m/ <ident> / for @Identifiers); # (bar hash Foo Foo your_ident anothers my)
```

In nqp's grammar, which is defined in NQP's [Grammar.nqp](https://github.com/perl6/nqp/blob/master/src/NQP/Grammar.nqp), there's:

```
token identifier { <.ident> [ <[\-']> <.ident> ]* }
```

In Raku's grammar, which is defined in Rakudo's [Grammar.nqp](https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/blob/master/src/Perl6/Grammar.nqp), there's code that looks slightly different but has the exact same effect:

```
token apostrophe { <[ ' \- ]> }
token identifier { <.ident> [ <.apostrophe> <.ident> ]* }
```

So `<identifier>` matches a pattern that includes one or more `<ident>`s with `<apostrophe>`s in between.

The `ident` method is in `NQPMatchRole`, which means it's a built-in that's part of the rule namespace of users' grammars.

But the `identifier` methods are **not** exported by either Raku or nqp. So they are **not** part of the rule namespace of users' grammars.

If we write our own `indentifier` token we can see it in action:

```
my token identifier { <.ident> [ <[\-']> <.ident> ]* }
my token sigil { <[$@%&]> }
say (~$/ if m/^ <sigil>? <identifier> $/ for @Identifiers)
```

displays:

```
($bar %hash Foo your_ident my-ident)
```

To summarize the above and some other considerations:

- `<ident>` matches just *parts* of what `<identifier>` matches (though they're the same for simple names). Consider `is-prime`. This is a Raku identifier but contains *two* `<ident>` matches (`is` and `prime`).
- `<identifier>` matches just *parts* of "Raku identifiers" (though they're the same for simple names). Consider `infix:<+>`. This is sometimes referred to as a Raku identifier but requires both an `<identifier>` match and a match of `:<+>`.
- Raku identifiers are themselves just *parts* of names (though they're the same for the simplest names). Consider `Foo-Bar::Baz-Qux` which contains *two* `<identifier>` matches (each in turn containing two `<ident>` matches).

## Footnotes

<sup>[1]</sup> If you're not sure what a capture is, see [Capturing](https://docs.raku.org/language/regexes#Capturing), [Named captures](https://docs.raku.org/language/regexes#Named_captures) and [Subrules](https://docs.raku.org/language/regexes#Subrules).

<sup>[2]</sup> The official specification of Raku is a test suite called roast -- the **R**epository **O**f **A**ll **S**pecification **T**ests. The latest version of a specific branch of [roast](https://github.com/perl6/roast) defines a specific version of Raku. When I first wrote this answer there had only been two *official* branches/versions of roast, and therefore of Raku. The first was [`6.c`](https://github.com/perl6/roast/tree/6.c) aka `6.Christmas`. This was [cut on Christmas day 2015](https://perl6advent.wordpress.com/2015/12/25/christmas-is-here/) and has been deliberately left frozen since that day. The second was `6.c.errata`, which conservatively added corrections to `6.c` deemed sufficiently important and backwards compatible to be included in the (then) current official recommended version of Raku. An "officially compliant" Raku compiler passes some official branch of roast. The Rakudo compiler (then) passed `6.c.errata`. If you read all the tests involving a feature in, say, the `6.c.errata` branch of roast, then you'll have read a full definition of the *officially specified* meaning of that feature for the `6.c.errata` version of the Raku language.

Comment: Back on rung one - this is a regex that matches a perl6 identifier - e.g. the name of a $variable (after the $). https://docs.perl6.org/language/syntax#Identifiers

Comment: @p6steve My apologies. I've completely rewritten the answer. It's not just the leading sigil. As you can see, `<ident>` also doesn't match a hyphen or apostrophe, hence `.Str.say for 'is-prime' ~~ m:g/ <ident> /; # is␤prime`. I'm going to update the last section in my answer to clarify this and also the difference between an identifier and an identifier-with-colon-pair and a name (latter allows `::`). Then some doc patches.

Answer (score 7):

In general, the place to look for the documentation is [Perl6 documentation](https://docs.perl6.org). That's part of a regex, [and you can find it in the definition of character classes](https://docs.perl6.org/language/regexes#Predefined_Character_Classes). It matches Perl6 identifiers. What the `.` in front of `ident` does is [to suppress capture](https://docs.perl6.org/language/regexes#Subrules).

Comment: Thanks a bunch. I had litte knowledge of what perl identifiers actually ment. The definition: (https://docs.perl6.org/language/syntax#Identifiers).

Comment: Docs tip: As of June 2018, if you search for something using the [docs.perl6.org](https://docs.perl6.org/) search box and you don't get a useful match in the drop down, you can add spaces to the end (sometimes needs 4 or 5) until you see `Not in Index (try web search)`. Clicking on that will google the docs for the word. In this case you should see `1 result`, namely [Regexes - Perl 6 Documentation](https://docs.perl6.org/language/regexes), with a bold **`<ident>`** shown at the start of the excerpt. Now you can go to the page and search for the word in the page.

Comment: @raiph there's [an issue to make that easier](https://github.com/perl6/doc/issues/1391). But we still have to get around to solve that...

Comment: "It matches Perl6 identifiers". I'd classify that as a [pedagogical facilitation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ORjyXcLDd9M&index=33&t=1m38s&list=PLRuESFRW2Fa77XObvk7-BYVFwobZHdXdK) worthy of [expansion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50688467/1077672).