# Why/how is an additional variable needed in matching repeated arbitary character with capture groups?

Tags: regex, raku

I'm matching a sequence of a repeating arbitrary character, with a minimum length, using a perl6 regex.

After reading through https://docs.perl6.org/language/regexes#Capture_numbers and tweaking the example given, I've come up with this code using an 'external variable':

```
#uses an additional variable $c
perl6 -e '$_="bbaaaaawer"; /((.){} :my $c=$0; ($c)**2..*)/ && print $0';

#Output:  aaaaa
```

To aid in illustrating my question only, a similar regex in perl5:

```
#No additional variable needed
perl -e ' $_="bbaaaaawer"; /((.)\2{2,})/ && print $1';
```

Could someone enlighten me on the need/benefit of 'saving' `$0` into `$c` and the requirement of the empty `{}`? Is there an alternative (better/golfed) perl6 regex that will match?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Shortest answer `/((.)$0**2..*)/`

Comment: Note that the whole point of the example was to create a short example which showed code that needed a lexical variable, but it did not explain why it needed it.`

Comment: Thank you all for the great answers! It's a shame I can only 'accept' one!  Reading the detail in all of them (multiple times!) I have a clearer understanding and realise I really need to look into perl6 Grammars. The link provided @raiph was a particularly intresting read.

Comment: Shorter answer to "Why/how is an additional variable needed in matching repeated arbitary character with capture groups?": It isn't. See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67078299/7270649

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Option #1: Don't sub-capture a pattern that includes a back reference

`$0` is a *back reference*<sup>1</sup>.

If you omit the sub-capture around the expression containing `$0`, then the code works:

```
$_="bbaaaaawer"; / (.) $0**2..* / && print $/; # aaaaa
```

Then you can also omit the `{}`. (I'll return to why you sometimes need to insert a `{}` later in this answer.)

---

But perhaps you wrote a sub-capture around the expression containing the back reference because you thought you needed the sub-capture for some other later processing.

There are often other ways to do things. In your example, perhaps you wanted a way to be able to count the number of repeats. If so, you could instead write:

```
$_="bbaaaaawer";
/ (.) $0**2..* /;
print $/.chars div $0.chars; # 5
```

Job done, without the complications of the following sections.

## Option #2. Sub-capture *without changing the current match object during matching of the pattern that includes a back reference*

Maybe you really need to sub-capture a match of an expression that includes a back reference.

This can still be done without needing to *surround* the `$0` with a sub-capture. This saves the problems discussed in the third section below.

You can use this technique if you don't need to have sub-sub-captures of the expression *and* the expression isn't too complicated:

```
$_="bbaaaaawer";
/ (.) $<capture-when-done>=$0**2..* /;
print $<capture-when-done>.join; # aaaa
```

This sub-captures the *result* of matching the expression in a named capture but avoids inserting an additional sub-capture context *around* the expression (which is what causes the complications discussed in the next section).

Unfortunately, while this technique will work for the expression in your question (`$0**2..*`) it won't if an expression is complex enough to need grouping. This is because the syntax `$<foo>=[...]` doesn't work. Perhaps this is fixable without hurting performance or causing other problems.<sup>2</sup>

## Option #3. Use a *saved* back reference *inside a sub-capture*

Finally we arrive at the technique you've used in your question.

Automatically available back references to sub-captures (like `$0`) *cannot* refer to sub-captures that happened *outside* the sub-capture they're written in. **Update** See "I'm (at least half) wrong!" note below.

So if, for any reason, you have to create a sub-capture (using either `(...)` or `<...>`) then you must manually store a back reference in a variable and use that instead.

Before we get to a final section explaining in detail why you must use a variable, let's first complete an initial answer to your question by covering the final wrinkle.

## `{}` forces "publication" of match results thus far

The `{}` is necessary to force the `:my $c=$0;` to update each time it's reached using the current regex/grammar engine. If you don't write it, then the regex engine fails to update `$c` to a capture of `'a'` and instead leaves it stuck on a capture of `'b'`.

Please read [**"Publication" of match variables by Rakudo**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51410261/1077672).

## Why *can't* a sub-capture include a back reference to captures that happened *outside* that sub-capture?

First, you have to take into account that matching in P6 is optimized for the nested matching case syntactically, semantically, and implementation wise.

In particular, if, when writing a regex or grammar, you write a numbered capture (with `(...)`), or a named rule/capture (with `<foo>`), then you've inserted a new level in a tree of sub-patterns that are dynamically matched/captured at run-time.

See [jnthn's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56395982/1077672) for why and [Brad's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56396843/1077672) for some discussion of details.

---

What I'll add to those answers is a (rough!) analogy, and another discussion of why you have to use a variable and `{}`.

The analogy begins with a tree of sub-directories in a file system:

```
/
  a
  b
    c
    d
```

The analogy is such that:

- The directory structure above corresponds to the result of a completed match operation.
- *After an overall match or grammar parse is complete*, the match object `$/` refers (analogously speaking) to the root directory.<sup>3</sup>
- The sub-directories correspond to sub-captures of the match.
- Numbered sub-matches/sub-captures `$0` and `$1` at the top level of the match operation shown below these bullet points corresponds to sub-directories `a` and `b`. The numbered sub-captures of the top level `$1` sub-match/sub-capture corresponds to the `c` and `d` sub-directories.
- *During matching* `$/` refers to the "current match object" which corresponds to the ["current working directory"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Working_directory).
- It's easy to refer to a sub-capture (sub-directory) of the current  match (current working directory).
- It's *impossible* to refer to a sub-capture (sub-directory) *outside* the current match (current working directory) unless you've saved a reference to that outside directory (capture) or a parent of it. That is, P6 does *not* include an analog of `..` or `/`! **Update** I'm happy to report that I'm (at least half) wrong! See [What's the difference between `$/` and `$¢` in regex?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61451103/whats-the-difference-between-and-%c2%a2-in-regex).

If file system navigation didn't support these back references towards the root then one thing to do would be to create an environment variable that stored a particular path. That's roughly what saving a capture in a variable in a P6 regex is doing.

The central issue is that a lot of the machinery related to regexes is *relative to "the current match"*. And this includes `$/`, which refers to the *current* match and back references like `$0`, which are *relative* to the current match. **Update** See "I'm (at least half) wrong!" note above.

---

Thus, in the following, which is [runnable via tio.run here](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7/18BCFTibZUSk5JTlKy5QNxcfQUNINRT0ASTEFa1QnFipYKKvkItVAAE9a0VlBXe712UlPx@7@JHE5YoGCjY2oEEoHywcRB91gpEAbBxILdADUwtSdb7/x8A), it's easy to display `'bc'` or `'c'` with a code block inserted in the third pair of parens...

```
$_="abcd";
m/ ( ( . ) ( . ( . ) { say $/ } ( . ) ) ) /; # ｢bc｣␤ 0 => ｢c｣␤
say $/;                                      # ｢abcd｣␤ etc.
```

...but it's *impossible* to refer to the captured `｢a｣` in that third pair of parens without storing `｢a｣`'s capture in a regular variable.  **Update** See "I'm (at least half) wrong!" note above.

Here's one way of looking at the above match:

```
  ↓ Start TOP level $/
m/ ( ( . ) ( . ( . ) { say $/ } ( . ) ) ) /; # captures ｢abcd｣

    ↓ Start first sub-capture; TOP's $/[0]
   (                                    )    # captures ｢abcd｣

      ↓ Start first sub-sub-capture; TOP's $/[0][0]
     ( . )                                   # captures ｢a｣

            ↓ Start *second* sub-sub-capture; TOP's $/[0][1]
           (                          )      # captures ｢bcd｣

                ↓ Start sub-sub-sub-capture; TOP's $/[0][1][0]
               ( . )                         # captures ｢c｣

                     { say $/ }              # ｢bc｣␤ 0 => ｢c｣␤

                                 ( . )       # captures 'd'
```

If we focus for a moment on what `$/` refers to *outside of the regex* (and also *directly* inside the `/.../` regex, but *not inside sub-captures*), then *that* `$/` refers to the *overall* `Match` object, which ends up capturing `｢abcd｣`. (In the filesystem analogy *this particular* `$/` is the root directory.)

The `$/` *inside the code block* inside the second sub-sub-capture refers to a lower level match object, specifically the one that, at the point the `say $/` is executed, has already matched `｢bc｣` and will go on to have captured `｢bcd｣` by the end of the overall match.

But there's *no built in way* to refer to the sub-capture of `'a'`, or the overall capture (which at that point would be `'abc'`), from within the sub-capture surrounding the code block. **Update** See "I'm (at least half) wrong!" note above.

Hence you have to do something like what you've done.

## A possible improvement?

What if there were a direct analog in P6 regexes for specifying the root? **Update** See "I'm (at least half) wrong!" note above.

Here's an initial cut at this that might make sense. Let's define a grammar:

```
my $*TOP;
grammar g {
  token TOP { { $*TOP := $/ } (.) {} <foo> }
  token foo { <{$*TOP[0]}> }
}
say g.parse: 'aa' # ｢aa｣␤ 0 => ｢a｣␤ foo => ｢a｣
```

So, perhaps a new variable could be introduced, one that's read only for userland code, that's bound to the *overall* match object during a match operation. **Update** See "I'm (at least half) wrong!" note above.

But then that's not only pretty ugly (unable to use a convenient short-hand back reference like `$0`) but refocuses attention on the need to also insert a `{}`. And given that it would presumably be *absurdly* expensive to republish *all* the tree of match objects after each atom, one is brought full circle back to the current status quo. Short of the fixes mentioned in this answer, I think what is currently implemented is as good as it's likely to get.

## Footnotes

<sup>1</sup> The current P6 doc doesn't use the conventional regex term "back reference" but `$0`, `$1` etc. are numbered P6 back references. The simplest explanation I've seen of numbered back references is [this SO about them using a different regex dialect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21880127/have-trouble-understanding-capturing-groups-and-back-references). In P6 they start with `$` instead of `\` and are numbered starting from `0` rather than `1`. The equivalent of `\0` in other regex dialects is `$/` in P6. In addition, `$0` is an alias for `$/[0]`, `$1` for `$/[1]`, etc.

<sup>2</sup> One might think this would work, but it doesn't:

```
$_="bbaaaaawer";
/ (.) $<doesn't-work>=[$0**2..*] /;
print $<doesn't-work>.join; # Use of Nil in string context
```

It seems that `[...]` doesn't mean "group, but don't insert a new capture level like `(...)` and `<...>` do" but instead "group, and do not capture". This renders the `$<doesn't-work>` in `$<doesn't-work>=[$0**2..*]` meaningless. Perhaps this can reasonably be fixed and perhaps it should be fixed.

<sup>3</sup> The current ["match variable" doc](https://docs.perl6.org/syntax/$$SOLIDUS) says:

> `$/` is the match variable. It stores the result of the last `Regex` match and so usually contains objects of type `Match`.

(Fwiw `$/` contains a *`List`* of `Match` objects if an adverb like `:global` or `:exhaustive` is used.)

The above description ignores a very important use case for `$/` which is its use *during matching*, in which case it contains the results *so far* of the *current* regex.

Following our file system analogy, `$/` is like the current working directory -- let's call it "the current working match object" aka CWMO. *Outside* a matching operation the CWMO (`$/`) is ordinarily the *completed result* of the *last* regex match or grammar parse. (I say "ordinarily" because it's writable so code can change it with as little as `$/ = 42`.) *During* matching (or [actions](https://docs.perl6.org/language/grammars#index-entry-Actions)) operations the CWMO is read-only for userland code and is bound to a `Match` object generated by the regex/grammar engine for the current match or action rule/method.

Answer (score 12):

Perl 6 regexes scale up to full grammars, which produce parse trees. Those parse trees are a tree of `Match` objects. Each capture - named or positional - is either a `Match` object or, if quantified, an array of `Match` objects.

This is in general good, but does involve making the trade-off you have observed: once you are on the inside of a nested capturing element, then you are populating a new `Match` object, with its own set of positional and named captures. For example, if we do:

```
say "abab" ~~ /((a)(b))+/
```

Then the result is:

```
｢abab｣
 0 => ｢ab｣
  0 => ｢a｣
  1 => ｢b｣
 0 => ｢ab｣
  0 => ｢a｣
  1 => ｢b｣
```

And we can then index:

```
say $0;        # The array of the top-level capture, which was quantified
say $0[1];     # The second Match
say $0[1][0];  # The first Match within that Match object (the (a))
```

It is a departure from regex tradition, but also an important part of scaling up to larger parsing challenges.

Comment: Does using a ':g' modifier potentially generates an array of `Match` objects similar to a quantifier also?

Comment: Yes; actually a `List` since it makes no sense to mutate it.

Answer (score 4):

The reason you have to store the capture into something other than `$0` is that every capturing `()` creates a new set of numbered captures.

So the `$0` inside of `($0)` can never refer to anything, because you didn't set `$0` inside of the `()`.

(The named captures `$<foo>` are also affected by this.)

---

The following has 3 separate `$0` “variables”, and one `$1` “variable”:

```perl6
'aabbaabb' ~~ / ^ ( (.)$0 ((.)$0) ) $0 $ /

'aabbaabb' ~~ /
                ^

                # $0 = 'aabb'
                (

                  # $0 = 'a'
                  (.) $0

                  # $1 = 'bb'
                  (

                    # $0 = 'b'
                    (.) $0
                  )
                )

                $0

                $
              /
```

```
｢aabbaabb｣
 0 => ｢aabb｣
  0 => ｢a｣
  1 => ｢bb｣
   0 => ｢b｣
```

Basically the `()` in the regex DSL act a bit like `{}` in normal Perl6.

A fairly direct if simplified translation of the above regex to “regular” Perl6 code follows.
(Pay attention to the 3 lines with `my $/ = [];`)
(Also the `/ ^ /` style comments refer to the regex code for `^` and such above)

```perl6
given 'aabbaabb' {
    my $/ = [];      # give assignable storage for $0, $1 etc.
    my $pos = 0;     # position counter
    my $init = $pos; # initial position

    # / ^ /
    fail unless $pos == 0;

    # / ( /
    $0 = do {
        my $/ = [];
        my $init = $pos;

        # / (.) $0 /
        $0 = .substr($pos,1); # / (.) /
        $pos += $0.chars;
        fail unless .substr($pos,$0.chars) eq $0; # / $0 /
        $pos += $0.chars;

        # / ( /
        $1 = do {
            my $/ = [];
            my $init = $pos;

            # / (.) $0 /
            $0 = .substr($pos,1); # / (.) /
            $pos += $0.chars;
            fail unless .substr($pos,$0.chars) eq $0; # / $0 /
            $pos += $0.chars;

        # / ) /
            # the returned value (becomes $1 in outer scope)
           .substr($init, $pos - $init)
        }

    # / ) /
        # the returned value (becomes $0 in outer scope)
        .substr($init, $pos - $init)
    }

    # / $0 /
    fail unless .substr($pos,$0.chars) eq $0;
    $pos += $0.chars;

    # / $ /
    fail unless $pos = .chars;

    # the returned value
    .substr($init, $pos - $init)
}
```

---

TLDR;

Just remove the `()` surrounding `($c)` / `($0)`.
(Assuming you didn't need the capture for something else.)

```perl6
/((.) $0**2..*)/
```

```bash
perl6 -e '$_="bbaaaaawer"; /((.) $0**2..*)/ && put $0';
```

Comment: Note that currently `/((.){} ("$0")**2..*)/` works, but I suspect that may be a bug. (The `$0` in `("$0")` refers to whatever was in `$0` at the time of `{}`.) At the very least it is surprising/confusing behavior.

Answer (score 2):

### **Start with a new Regex**

You appear to have discovered a sophisticated mechanism by which captures within a single regex can be accessed and utilized for further matching *within the same regex.* The Raku Docs refer to this technique as  "publishing" the capture.

However, your regex needn't be so sophisticated since Raku provides constructs that can do much of the heavy-lifting for you (below code run in the Raku REPL):

```
> put $/ if "bbaaaaawer" ~~ m:g/ (.)+ % <same>  /;
bb aaaaa w e r
> put $/.sort(*.chars).reverse if "bbaaaaawer" ~~ m:g/ (.)+ % <same>  /;
aaaaa bb r e w
> put $/.sort(*.chars).reverse.[0] if "bbaaaaawer" ~~ m:g/ (.)+ % <same>  /;
aaaaa
```

The regex above uses two features of Raku regexes: 1) sequential identical characters can be matched using the zero-width `<same>` "Pre-defined Regex" character class, and 2) the matching of patterns "separated" by a known character (for example, a comma), can be accomplished with either the `%` or `%%` "Modified Quantifier" separator-denotation mark(s).

Note, you can simply change the `+` quantifier in `(.)+` to whatever quantity you desire. Capturing three-or-more consecutive identical characters can be accomplished thusly (note--curlies around `{3..*}` are optional):

```
> put $/ if "bbaaaaawer" ~~ m:g/ (.) ** {3..*}  % <same>  /;
aaaaa
> put $0 if "bbaaaaawer" ~~ m:g/ (.) ** {3..*}  % <same>  /;
aaaaa
```

1. https://docs.raku.org/language/regexes#Predefined_Regexes
2. https://docs.raku.org/language/regexes#Modified_quantifier:_%,_%%