# Backreferences in regexes match, but do not capture

Tags: regex, raku

This program

```
say "zipi zape" ~~ /(\w)\w» \s+ \w+({$0})/;
```

returns

```
｢pi zape｣
 0 => ｢p｣
 1 => ｢｣
```

which I interpret as the backreference to the first match being matched to a zero-width match? Maybe because it's matched to $0, which is itemized to '' outside the regex? How could I use these backreferences, and capture at the same time the match?
**Note**: this related to [this documentation issue](https://github.com/perl6/doc/issues/1545), which requires clarification of the use of backreferences.

Comment: At the time of writing this all the issues raised and questions asked in your original question **and** in your comments on Håkon's answer are carefully explained in [my answer to "Why/how is an additional variable needed in matching repeated arbitary character with capture groups?"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56397290/1077672). Do you think it's worth walking thru your version of the problem and questions? I will happily write an answer if you read my linked answer and think yours is different but for now I think it's essentially a duplicate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`{$0}` isn't a backreference.
It is a code block.
In this case, it is a code block which does absolutely nothing.

In order for it to actually be used as a part of the regex it needs `<>` around it.

---

In fact since `()` denotes something like a new closure in respect of `$/`, it would be an empty regex if it was actually being used for something.
(`$/` is reset for every `()`, so `$0` is also reset.)

```perl6
say "zipi zape" ~~ /(\w)\w» \s+ \w+(<{$0}>)/;
```

```
Cannot resolve caller INTERPOLATE_ASSERTION(Match:D: Nil:U, BOOTInt, BOOTInt, BOOTInt, BOOTInt, PseudoStash:D); none of these signatures match:
    (Match: Associative:D, $, $, $, $, $, *%_)
    (Match: Iterable:D \var, int \im, int \monkey, int \s, $, \context, *%_)
    (Match: Mu:D \var, int \im, int \monkey, $, $, \context, *%_)
  in block <unit> at <unknown file> line 1
```

That happens because it is basically the same as `(<{Nil}>)`.

---

What you could do is update `$/` before the second `()` by using `{}`, and use double quotes around `$0`

```perl6
say "zipi zape" ~~ /(\w){}\w» \s+ \w+("$0")/;
｢pi zap｣
 0 => ｢p｣
 1 => ｢p｣
```

Too me this seems a little unreliable.
(It is relying on what I would consider a mis-feature, if not an outright bug.)

---

This is where we get to Håkon Hægland's answer of storing it in a lexical variable.
(After updating `$/` by using `{}`.)

```perl6
say "zipi zape" ~~ /(\w){} :my $c = $0; \w » \s+ \w+($c)/;
```

Lexical variables are not scoped to `()`, so it is perfectly safe to do this.

I would personally stringify `$0` since that is the only part of the match object inside of `$0` that is being used.

```perl6
say "zipi zape" ~~ /(\w){} :my $c = ~$0; \w » \s+ \w+($c)/;
```

---

Honestly I don't see a reason to even capture the second match, since it is always going to be the same as the first match.

```perl6
say "zipi zape" ~~ /(\w)\w» \s+ \w+$0/;
```

I also see little point in adding `»` since the `\s+` already forces it to be the end of a word.

```perl6
say "zipi zape" ~~ /(\w)\w \s+ \w+$0/;
```

Answer (score 4):

According to the [documentation](https://docs.perl6.org/language/regexes#Capturing):

> If you need to refer to a capture from within another capture, store it in a variable first

So you could use:

```
say "zipi zape" ~~ /(\w){} :my $c = $0; \w » \s+ \w+($c)/;
```

**Output**:

```
｢pi zap｣
 0 => ｢p｣
 1 => ｢p｣
```

Comment: Actually, I wanted to understand above behavior. But there's an additional thing I kind of not-understand; why do you use open and closing braces behind the first capture?

Comment: It seems this usage of `{}` is only mentioned in a [comment](https://github.com/perl6/doc/blob/master/doc/Language/regexes.pod6#L1088): it says we need it to update the current match object.

Comment: Hi @jjmerelo "I wanted to understand above behavior." In brief, `(...)` is shorthand for creating a new `Match` object and setting `$/` to that new object inside the parens. So your second pair of parens means that the `$0` inside them does *not* refer back to the (capture from the) first pair of parens.

Comment: @jjmerelo "why do you use open and closing braces behind the first capture" I've explained this (both in summary and in great depth) in prior SOs; see my comment on your question as a starting point.

Comment: @raiph Thanks for the reference to the other question!