# Raku regex: How to use capturing group inside lookbehinds

Tags: regex, raku, lookbehind, rakudo

How can I use capturing groups inside lookbehind assertions?

I tried to use the same formula as in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64902024/7500028). But that does not seem to work with lookbehinds.

*Conceptually*, this is what I was trying to do.

```
say "133" ~~ m/ <?after $0+> (\d) $ /
```

I know this can be easily achieved without lookbehinds, but ignore that just for now :)

For this I tried with these options:

Use `:var` syntax:

```
say "133" ~~ m/ <?after $look-behind+> (\d):my $look-behind; $ /;
# Variable '$look-behind' is not declared
```

Use `code block` syntax defining the variable outside:

```
my $look-behind;
say "133" ~~ m/ <?after $look-behind+> (\d) {$look-behind=$0} $ /;
# False
```

It seems that the problem is that the `lookbehind` is executed before the "code block/:my $var", and thus the variable is empty for the lookbehind tree.

Is there a way to use capturing groups inside lookbehinds?

Comment: A, er, curiosity: `say .<after> given foo ~~ m/ $ <after bar> /` will work for any string in `foo` that ends with the pattern `bar`, which is fair enough... and displays a capture that's the string in `foo` *in its entirety* (not just `bar`) and entirely *flipped* (backwards)! 

Comment: "I know this can be easily achieved without lookbehinds, but ignore that just for now :)" I've ignored that for a day, but now's a new now. :) So, what is it that you're *really* trying to do?

Comment: Regexes in Raku are code. You wouldn't expect a variable to have data in it before you set it, so why would you expect the same from a Regex?

Comment: Hi @raiph I tried to solve Day 15 of advent of code using regexes (and inline code in them). I finally reversed the input numbers and used lookeaheads instead of lookbehinds. But, I figured there would exist a way to reference capturing groups in lookbehinds using raku, so I asked... :)

Comment: @BradGilbert Well, I was not expecting anything xD, that was something I tried just in case...

Comment: @Julio Thanks. I figured out what you were asking after I posted my comments. In case you haven't yet figured this out, using jnthn's answer to your previous Q about *lookahead* (`/ (a) :my $lookahead; <?before b {$lookahead = $/}> /`), a simple translation of that to a *lookbehind* version solving this Q would be `/ (a) :my $lookbehind; { $lookbehind = $/ } <?after $lookbehind ** 2> $ /;`. (Which is more or less the same as .@WiktorStribiżew's answer.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you reference a captured value before it is actually captured, it is not initialized, hence you can't get a match. You need to define the capturing group before actually using the backreference to the captured value.

Next, you need to define a code block and assign the backreference to a variable to be used throughout the regex pattern, else, it is not visible to the lookbehind pattern. See [this *Capturing* Raku reference](https://docs.raku.org/language/regexes#Capturing):

> This code block publishes the capture inside the regex, so that it can be assigned to other variables or used for subsequent matches

You can use something like

```
say "133" ~~ m/ (\d) {} :my $c=$0; <?after $c ** 2> $ /;
```

Here, `(\d)` matches and captures a digit, then a code block is used to assign this captured value to a `$c` variable, and then the `<?after $c ** 2>` lookbehind checks if the `$c` value appears at least twice immediately to the left of the current location, and then the `$` anchor checks if the current position is the end of the string.

See [this online Raku demo](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7/784sVJBydDYWEmhrk4hV19BIyZFU6G6VsEqt1JBJdlWxcBawcY@Ma0ktQjIVdDSUjCyU1BR0Lf@/x8A).

Comment: Superb! Nice trick to postpone the lookbehind and read again the captured group on it!

Comment: It would be worth pointing out that the reason `{}` is needed is so that `$/` gets updated. ( `$0` is really a shortcut for `$/[0]`)