# Elegant way to find repeated digits in Raku (née Perl 6)

Tags: regex, raku

I'm trying to find groups of repeated digits in a number, e.g. `12334555611` becomes `(1 2 33 4 555 6 11)`.

This works:

```
$n.comb(/ 0+ | 1+ | 2+ | 3+ | 4+ | 5+ | 6+ | 7+ | 8+ | 9+ /)
```

but is not very elegant.

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Just to check `11223311` should become `(11 22 33 11)` and not `(1111 22 33)`?

Comment: @Scimon: correct.

Comment: @Elizabeth Mattijsen: I know Perl 6 has been renamed, but must you really erase all traces of the name?  That prevents people from finding this question by searching on [perl6 repeated digits], for instance.

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/391656/why-are-no-more-perl-6-questions-asked-on-stack-overflow for evidence that this may be a bad idea,

Comment: @mscha: I propose that *if* the op mentions Perl 6 in the title, we change this to "Raku (née Perl 6)".

Comment: @Elizabeth Mattijsen: yes, something like that makes sense.  I had “Perl 6 (Raku)” originally.  But in the tags I had both `perl6` and `raku`, is it really necessary to _remove_ the `perl6` tag?  (Now people that follow the `perl6` tag but not (yet) the `raku` tag won't see my post.)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
'12334555611'.comb(/\d+ % <same>/)
```

[Please check the answer of the first task of Perl Weekly Challenge](https://perlweeklychallenge.org/blog/perl-weekly-challenge-020/)

Comment: Nice one!  I had already accepted Wiktor's answer, but this one is even more elegant!

Answer (score 6):

You may use

```
$n.comb(/(.) $0*/)
```

The `(.)` creates a capturing group and captures any char into Group 1, then there is a backreference to Group 1 that is `$0` in Perl6 regex. The `*` quantifier matches zero or more occurrences of the same char as in Group 1.

Replace the `.` with `\d` to match any digit if you need to only match repeated digits.

See a [Perl6 demo online](https://ideone.com/HXwIys).

Comment: Thanks.  The elegance of this is debatable  but it is a better solution than my original one.

Comment: Beats my attempt `( $n ~~ m/@<groups>=((<[0..9]>)$0+)*/ ).<groups>.map( *.Str )`

Comment: @Wiktor, it's the `{}` that makes me find the elegance debatable.   But to my surprise, it doesn't seem to be necessary, `$n.comb(/(.) $0*/)` works as well (at least on my Rakudo Star 2019.03.1).

Comment: @mscha OK, when I first tried it, it did not work. Good, let me change the link and the code.

Comment: @mscha "to my surprise, it [`{}`] doesn't seem to be necessary" My discussion of related issues in the first couple sections of [**"Publication" of match variables by Rakudo**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51408141/perl6-grammar-not-sure-about-some-syntax-in-an-example/51410261#51410261) may help clear up why. (Perhaps in the sense that some folk use mud to try clear up acne, but I thought I'd comment anyway.)

Answer (score 0):

In case someone navigates here wanting to remove singleton digits (Raku REPL code below):

1. Returning only the longest run(s) of repeated digits, while removing singleton digits (uses `m:g` adverb combo):

```
    > put $/ if m:g/ \d**2..* % <same> / given '12334555611';
    33 555 11
```

2. Alternatively, depending on how you interpret the original question, returning the *overlapping runs* of repeated digits (uses `m:ov` adverb combo):

```
    > put $/ if m:ov/ \d**2..* % <same> / given '12334555611';
    33 555 55 11
```

The difference between the two versions is particularly dramatic as repeated runs get longer:

```
    > given '122333444455555666666' {put $/ if m:g/ \d**2..* % <same> /};
    22 333 4444 55555 666666

    > given '122333444455555666666' {put $/ if m:ov/ \d**2..* % <same> /};
    22 333 33 4444 444 44 55555 5555 555 55 666666 66666 6666 666 66
```