# What is the correct Raku recursive regex syntax?

Tags: raku

What or how is Raku recursive regex syntax and all match variable in Raku as on try

```
'hellohelloworldworld' ~~ m{ ^(h\w+?o) (?0) world  };
say "\n=$&"
```

seems to not work

Please help out solving these.

Comment: @raiph This question should have an answer regarding "publication of a match variable." Please consider reposting, thx.

Comment: @raiph yes but you're citing an answer to a question initially posted 3.5 years ago. I for one expect the compiler to have evolved since then, so that what may have been considered a bug back then has either 1) been enshrined in the docs, or 2) has been obviated. Which is to say...going forward, a 2022 **updated** answer from you regarding  *"Publication" of match variables by Rakudo* would be most prized. Regards.

Comment: @raiph Still hoping to confirm/refute whether 'publication' of a match-variable is still required (or not). As mentioned previously, I get the desired answer with `say $/ if 'hellohelloworldoworld' ~~ m/ ^(h\w+?o) {$0} world /;`. And I'm running that in REPL version `moar (2021.06)`.

Comment: Aaah. I've been playing with the wrong input string (...`worldoworld`). Now I see: `say $/ if 'hellohelloworldworld' ~~ m/ ^(h\w+?o) {} $0 world /;` works properly. My tests indicate "publication" is indeed still required.

Comment: @jubilatious I think it was changed in the question, so not your mistake :-)

Answer (score 8):

Raku has dedicated syntax for anonymous [recursive regexes](https://docs.raku.org/language/regexes#Recursive_Regexes) :`<~~>`.

Using this syntax, you could write the regex in your question as:

```raku
'hellohelloworldworld' ~~ m{ ^(h\w+?o) <~~>? world  };

say $/; # OUTPUT: «｢hellohelloworld｣␤
        #          0 => ｢hellohello｣␤»
```

Comment: "I didn't plagiarize, honest teach!" :) (I prepared an edit of my answer covering self-recursion, and a bogus-but-maybe-interesting "Answer #3", hours ago. But I lost net connection (it's yoyoing today due to Storm Corrie), and then got waylaid, before publishing it (just now).)

Comment: Confused, because without `<~~>?` the code `say $/ if 'hellohelloworldworld' ~~ m{ ^(h\w+?o) world  };` still returns the same result. I'm on REPL version `moar (2021.06)`.

Answer (score 3):

The two answers I expected to see have already been posted, they are:

1. " `{}` publication" of a match variable for use later within the
   same regex/matching operation (technically a *backreference*):

```perl
    > say $/ if 'hellohelloworldworld' ~~ m/ ^(h\w+?o) {} $0 world /;
    ｢hellohelloworld｣
     0 => ｢hello｣
    > say $/ if 'hellohelloworldworld' ~~ m/ ^(h\w+?o) world /;
    ｢hellohelloworld｣
     0 => ｢hellohello｣
```

and,

2. use of Raku's dedicated " `<~~>` recursing-match" operator
   within the regex.

In true TMTOWTDI-spirit, there is however a third option, using Raku's `:nd()` adverb to achieve a sort of "poor-man's" recursion. Starting from the `['(' \w* ]` grouping, you can successively pull out `｢(bird｣`, `｢(in｣`, and `｢(nest｣` from the input string `(bird(in(nest)))`. Or all three at once (last example):

In the Raku REPL:

```perl
> my $nested = "(bird(in(nest)))";
(bird(in(nest)))
> say $nested;
(bird(in(nest)))
> say  $nested ~~ m:1st/ ['(' \w* ] /;
｢(bird｣
> say  $nested ~~ m:2nd/ ['(' \w* ] /;
｢(in｣
> say  $nested ~~ m:3rd/ ['(' \w* ] /;
｢(nest｣
> say  $nested ~~ m:nd(1..3)/ ['(' \w* ] /;
(｢(bird｣ ｢(in｣ ｢(nest｣)
>
```

Behind the scenes this is most likely using Raku's `:position` adverb or `:continue` adverb, in conjunction with Raku's `$/.to` match variable:

```perl
> say  $nested ~~ m/ ['(' \w* ] /;
｢(bird｣
> say  $nested ~~ m:pos($/.to)/ ['(' \w* ] / given $nested ~~ m/ ['(' \w* ] /;
｢(in｣
> say  $nested ~~ m:pos($/.to)/ ['(' \w* ] / given $nested ~~ (m/ ['(' \w* ] / && m:pos($/.to)/ ['(' \w* ] /);
｢(nest｣
>
```

Again, Raku gives you a lot of different ways to approach the problem, which is one of the niceties of the language.

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/51410261/7270649
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/51409621/7270649
- https://examples.perl6.org/categories/parsers/SimpleStrings.html